# Mouseover issues in D3.js, containing Path elements and changing tooltip data once focus is brushed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I'm having the following issues with a Multi Series, Focus + Context D3 chart and thought I'd try to get the answers to my main questions in one go.

The questions I have are as follows:

1. How do I ensure the tooltips I've created are not affected by the hair-line (which follows the mouse) of the chart i.e. do not disappear and instead persist until the mouse is moved? This is how they would behave if the hair-line was not visible or had been created.
2. For some reason (probably obvious but not to me) the paths of data are not constrained to the focus area and spill out to the left of the chart. How does one solve this? I realise it's something to do with the left margin, probably.
3. Lastly when the data is brushed, the focus chart updates via the context but I'm struggling to update the tooltip data. Can anyone see what's wrong with the existing code?

The CSS:

```
        body {
          font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis path_steelblue {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
        }

        .path_steelblue {
            fill: none;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .path_blue {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #3333FF;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
        .path_red {
            fill: none;
            stroke:red;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
        .path_yellow {
            fill: none;
            stroke:yellow;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .brush .extent {
            stroke: #FFF;
            fill-opacity: .125;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;         
            stroke: grey;       
            stroke-width: 1;     
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        .grid .tick {
            stroke: lightgrey;
            opacity: 0.7;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        .grid path {
            stroke-width: 0;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .dot {
            fill: white;
            stroke: white;
            opacity:0.01;
            stroke-width: 0px;
            cursor:crosshair;
        }

        div.tooltip {   
            position: absolute;           
            text-align: left;           
            width: 120px;                  
            height: 48px;                 
            padding: 10px;             
            font: 12px sans-serif;        
            background: steelblue;   
            border: 0px;      
            border-radius: 8px;           
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        div.tooltipSolvency {       
            background: #3333FF;
        }

        div.tooltipTechnical {       
            background: red;
        }

        div.tooltipAccounting {       
            background: yellow;
        }

        .hover-line { 
            stroke: #000;
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 1px;
            left: 10px;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .hover-text {
            stroke: none;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            fill: #000000;
        }
```

The D3 code:

```
        var margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40 },
            margin2 = { top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse;
        var formatTime = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y");

        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
            x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
            y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
            xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
            yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

        var brush = d3.svg.brush()
            .x(x2)
            .on("brush", brushed);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.chartValue); });

        var line2 = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y2(d.chartValue); });

        var svg = d3.select(".tracker-chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
            //.style("margin-left", "40px")
            //.style("margin-top", "40px");

        //var container = svg.append("g")
        //  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        //  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
          .append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var focus = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "focus")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Hover line. 
        var hoverLineGroup = svg.append("g") //svg.append("g") -- Ensures hairline follows mouse pointer put interferes with the tooltip not allowing it to persist until the mouse moves again
            .attr("class", "hover-line");

        var hoverLine = hoverLineGroup
            .append("line")
                .attr("x1", 10).attr("x2", 10) 
                .attr("y1", 0).attr("y2", height + 10);

        var hoverDate = hoverLineGroup.append('text')
            .attr("class", "hover-text")
            .attr('y', height - (height-10));

        // Hide hover line by default.
        hoverLine.style("opacity", 1e-6);

        var div = d3.select(".tracker-chart").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        var divSolvency = d3.select(".tracker-chart").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip tooltipSolvency")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        var divTechnical = d3.select(".tracker-chart").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip tooltipTechnical")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        var divAccounting = d3.select(".tracker-chart").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip tooltipAccounting")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        var context = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "context")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

        d3.xml("data.xml", "application/xml", function(error, data) {
            var assetResultsData = d3.select(data).select("AssetResults").selectAll("Result");
            assetResultsData[0].forEach(crunch);

            var liabilityResultsDataSol = d3.select(data).selectAll("LiabilityResults Liability[name='Solvency'] Results Item");
            liabilityResultsDataSol[0].forEach(crunch);

            var liabilityResultsDataTP = d3.select(data).selectAll("LiabilityResults Liability[name='Technical provisions'] Results Item");
            liabilityResultsDataTP[0].forEach(crunch);

            var liabilityResultsDataTV = d3.select(data).selectAll("LiabilityResults Liability[name='Accounting'] Results Item");
            liabilityResultsDataTV[0].forEach(crunch);

            x.domain(d3.extent(assetResultsData[0], function (d) { return d.date; }));
            y.domain([450, 600]); //Hard coded for demo purposes
            //y.domain(d3.extent(assetResultsData[0], function (d) { return d.chartValue; }));
            x2.domain(x.domain());
            y2.domain(y.domain());

            focus.append("path")
                .datum(assetResultsData[0])
                .attr("class", "path_steelblue")
                .attr("d", line);

            focus.append("path")
                .datum(liabilityResultsDataSol[0])
                .attr("class", "path_blue")
                .attr("d", line);

            focus.append("path")
                .datum(liabilityResultsDataTV[0])
                .attr("class", "path_red")
                .attr("d", line);

            focus.append("path")
                .datum(liabilityResultsDataTP[0])
                .attr("class", "path_yellow")
                .attr("d", line);

            focus.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            focus.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Millions ($)");

            focus.append("g")
                .attr("class", "grid")
                .call(make_y_axis()
                    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                    .tickFormat("")
                );

            context.append("path")
                .datum(assetResultsData[0])
                .attr("class", "path_steelblue")
                .attr("d", line2);

            context.append("path")
                .datum(liabilityResultsDataSol[0])
                .attr("class", "path_blue")
                .attr("d", line2);

            context.append("path")
                .datum(liabilityResultsDataTV[0])
                .attr("class", "path_yellow")
                .attr("d", line2);

            context.append("path")
                .datum(liabilityResultsDataTP[0])
                .attr("class", "path_red")
                .attr("d", line2);

            context.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
                .call(xAxis2);

            context.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x brush")
                .call(brush)
            .selectAll("rect")
                .attr("y", -6)
                .attr("height", height2 + 7);

            addTooltip(div, assetResultsData[0], "Assets");
            addTooltip(divSolvency, liabilityResultsDataSol[0], "Solvency");
            addTooltip(divTechnical, liabilityResultsDataTV[0], "Technical Provisions");
            addTooltip(divAccounting, liabilityResultsDataTP[0], "Accounting");
        });

        // Add mouseover events for hover line.
        d3.select(".tracker-chart").on("mouseover", function() {
            }).on("mousemove", function() {
                    //console.log('mousemove', d3.mouse(this));
                    var mouse_x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
                    var mouse_y = d3.mouse(this)[1];
                    var graph_y = y.invert(mouse_y);
                    var graph_x = x.invert(mouse_x);
                    //console.log(graph_x);
                    var format = d3.time.format('%a %b %d %Y');
                    hoverDate.text(format(graph_x));
                    hoverDate.attr('x', mouse_x);
                    //console.log(x.invert(mouse_x));
                    hoverLine.attr("x1", mouse_x).attr("x2", mouse_x)
                    hoverLine.style("opacity", 1);
                }).on("mouseout", function() {
                    //hoverLine.style("opacity", 1e-6);
                });

        function addTooltip(div, data, label) {
            focus.selectAll("dot")
                    .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "dot")
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.chartValue); })
                        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                            div.transition()
                                .duration(50)
                                .style("opacity", .9);
                            div.html(label + "<br />" + formatTime(d.date) + "<br />" + "$" + (d.chartValue).toFixed(3) + " Million")
                                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

                    }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
                        div.transition()
                            .duration(200)
                            .style("opacity", 0);
                    });
                    /*
            focus.on('mouseover', function(){
                brush_elm = focus.select("circle").node();
                console.log(brush_elm);
                console.log(this);
                new_click_event = new Event('mouseover');
                new_click_event.pageX = d3.event.pageX;
                new_click_event.clientX = d3.event.clientX;
                new_click_event.pageY = d3.event.pageY;
                new_click_event.clientY = d3.event.clientY;
                brush_elm.dispatchEvent(new_click_event);
            });*/
        }

        function brushed() {
            x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
            focus.select(".path_steelblue").attr("d", line);
            focus.select(".path_blue").attr("d", line);
            focus.select(".path_yellow").attr("d", line);
            focus.select(".path_red").attr("d", line);
            focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        }

        function make_y_axis() {        
            return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(5)
        }

        function crunch(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.getAttribute("date"));
            d.chartValue = +d.getAttribute("value")/ 1000000;
            d.hoverText = +d.getAttribute("value");
        }
```

**EDIT**

Image included: [image: Multi Series Focus + Context Graph]

**NEW EDIT**

```
    // Hover line. 
        var hoverLineGroup = focus.append("g") //svg.append("g") -- Ensures hairline follows mouse pointer put interferes with the tooltip not allowing it to persist until the mouse moves again
            .attr("class", "hover-line");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to have an object follow the mouse but not interfere with the ability of the mouse to trigger events on underlying objects, give it the style [`pointer-events:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events).
2. If you want drawing elements to only show up in a limited plotting area, you'll need to apply a [clipping path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path) attribute *to the group that contains those elements*.  You've copied the code to create the `clipPath` element, but are never attaching it to a group.
3. I'm not sure exactly what you want to happen versus what is happening.  Can you explain more clearly, preferably with a link to a working example?  You don't have anything in your `brushed` function relating to tooltips.  At the least, you should be selecting any existing tooltips and repositioning them based on the updated x-scale function.

**Edit in response to comment**

If all you're trying to do with the tooltip is move it to match the zoom, that is fairly straightforward.  You just need to re-set the x-coordinate after you change the domain of the x-scale:

```
    function brushed() {
        x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());

        focus.selectAll("circle.dot") 
             //or you could just use ".dot" 
             //but NOT "dot", which you have in your initialization code!
             .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); } );

        focus.select(".path_steelblue").attr("d", line);
        focus.select(".path_blue").attr("d", line);
        focus.select(".path_yellow").attr("d", line);
        focus.select(".path_red").attr("d", line);
        focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }
```

By the way, it would be a lot more efficient if you gave your lines two classes, one common to all of them and one unique to each data type.  Just separate the classes with space:

```
        context.append("path")
            .datum(assetResultsData[0])
            .attr("class", "datapath steelblue")
            .attr("d", line);
```

Then in CSS your selector for any properties that apply to *all* the paths would be

```
path.datapath {
}
```

or

```
g.focus path.datapath {
}
```

if you only want styles to apply to the lines in the main chart (e.g., if you wanted to have a thicker stroke-width in the main chart compared to the small context chart).

Of course, you could still select individual lines using both classes:

```
path.datapath.steelblue {
    stroke: steelblue;
}
```

Since d3 select functions use the same selectors, in your brushed function you can use the common selector to select *all* the data lines in one go and update them.

```
    function brushed() {
        x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());

        focus.selectAll("circle.dot") 
             .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); } );

        focus.selectAll("path.datapath").attr("d", line);

        focus.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }
```

The `line` is a function that creates the path information based on the data from each element and the x and y scales you assigned when you created the line function.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer to question (1) was exactly what I was looking for. I think I know what to do with question (2) so I'm working on that now. With regards to question (3) I'm using XML data, of which there is a lot (I could reduce it though) and I'm having trouble posting it. So a working example is difficult to show. I've added an image of the what the chart looks like. Repositioning the existing tooltips (see code) is what I'm trying to do, just not sure how.

Comment: Thanks @AmeliaBR the tooltip problem has now been solved and I've used your recommendations with regards to the CSS.

Comment: Still struggling to contain the paths when 'brushing'. The paths seem to be contained by the focus group which is what I thought the clipping was happening on (apparently not). This also causes another issue with the hover-line date, which after 'brushing' is slightly out of sync when appended to the `svg` element. (See new edit) If appended to the `focus` element the date is in sync but the hair-line is not aligned with the mouse pointer.

Comment: For the clipping path, you need to add the attribute to the focus `<g>` element: `focus.attr("clipping-path", "url(#clip)");`  For positioning your mouse-tracking line, you need the mouse coordinates relative to the SVG that is the parent of the elements you're positioning: `var mouse_x = d3.mouse( svg.node() )[0];`.  Then to get the correct value from the inverted scale, you need the mouse coordinates relative to the focus `<g>` element that contains the graph: `var graph_x = x.invert( d3.mouse( focus.node() ) );`.

Comment: Thanks again @AmeliaBR. It was just the focus.node() that I needed to use for the hair-line mouse-tracking. and for the clipping I used `clip-path` as opposed to `clipping-path`! +3 for all 3 questions answered. Thanks.